# How to make not to redirect after login ajax request cakephp 3

Tags: php, ajax, redirect, cakephp-3.0

I was use better noti to get new noticount without page refresh. But when i login to system, redirect to this noticount function.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#notification").notify_better({
            interval: 8000,
            url: "<?=$this->url->build('/bookings/noticount')?>",
            type:'GET',
            updateFavicon: {
              id: "favicon",
              location: "full",
              shape: "circle"
            },
            done: function() {
              $(".main > p").html("Notification retrieved. Check out the <strong>favicon</strong> above!<br><small>You can clear all these by clicking the clear button.</small>")
            }
          });


      </script>
```

Comment: From what I can understand, you probably want to use [event.preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/).

Comment: please explain properly. i have not understand when you redirect.

Comment: @Tonystark When i was login, the login is redirect to /bookings/noticount ajax rquest.